# Certificate errors using an internal identity provider from one realm to another in Keycloak

Tags: ssl, keycloak, keycloak-services, identity-provider

## Overview

Following the answer of another [Keycloak identity provider thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65017085/how-to-check-authenticate-keycloak-instance-a-user-from-another-keycloak-instanc/65017806#65017806), I have two realms setup to keep users separate. The *`external realm`* contains a **Keycloak OpenID Connect** `identity provider` to the *`internal realm`*. Within the *`external realm`* there is a `client` configured which allows my application to validate users through a `client adapter`.

I am using Keycloak version `18.0.0`.

## Configuration

Any setting not specified is OFF, not set (blank entry), or the default.

The `identity provider` configured in the *`external realm`* has the following settings:

- `Enabled: true`
- `Store Tokens: ON`
- `Trust Email: ON`
- `First Login Flow: first broker login`
- `Sync Mode: force`
- ODIC settings:

  - `Auth URL`, `Token URL`, `Logout URL`, and `User Info URL` all set to the the matching *`internal realm`* client
  - `Client Authentication: Client secret sent as basic auth`
  - `Client Secret` set to matching client secret
  - `Issuer` set to *`internal realm`* URL. Ex: `https://<hostname>/auth/realms/<internalRealmName>`
  - `Default Scopes: openid`
  - `Prompt: unspecified`
  - `Validate Signatures: ON`
  - Use `JWKS URL: ON`, `JWKS URL` set to matching *`internal realm`* cert location. EX: `https://<hostname>/auth/realms/<internalRealmName>/protocol/openid-connect/certs`
  - `Use PKCE: ON`
  - `PKCE Method: S256`

The `client` configured in the *`internal realm`* has the following settings:

- `Enabled: true`
- `Client Protocol: openid-connect`
- `Access Type: confidential`
- `Standard Flow Enabled: ON`
- `Valid Redirect URIs: https://<hostname>/auth/realms/<externalRealmName>/broker/<internalRealmName>/endpoint`
- `Backchannel Logout Session Required: ON`
- `Credentials`

  - `Client Authenticator: Client Id and Secret`
  - Secret copied over and set in the *`external realm`* `identity provider` configuration

## Problem

Users that exist in the *`external realm`* can login, as well as users that are configured to login through another separate external ODIC `identity provider` (This is **not** the identity provider to the *`internal realm`*, just an example that the identity provider login flow is working).

Users that attempt to login via the `identity provider` to the *`internal realm`* cannot login. The login page displays `Unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider`.

Checking the Keycloak logs, I see the following error:

```
WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-405) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=<externalRealmName>, clientId=<externalRealmClientName>, userId=null, ipAddress=<removed>, error=identity_provider_login_failure, code_id=258c44bd-88fc-44a1-b93c-18225b00df49

ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (default task-405) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

## Request for help

Why would Keycloak be failing to validate the certificate when using this `identity provider`? It is able to authenticate successfully using the SSL setup for the *`external realm`* as well as another `identity provider` for an external connection. I can't figure out where the Keycloak certification failure is really happening.